# When creating models in Django, should database normalization be taken into consideration?

Tags: django, rdbms, database-normalization

I'm new to Django and web frameworks in general, but have worked with DBMSs quite often.  Knowing that each class within django models maps to a table in the database, should the models be based on an ERD where tables are normalized?  Would normal form matter in this case?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're using a SQL backend (i.e. not something like mongodb), then the same guidelines for normalisation would apply.  Remember, django is just a pretty way to access the database, but in the backgroud you're still executing a series of sql queries which will benefit in the same way from normalisation.

That said, a lot of the business logic that you would normally build into the database can now be handled by django, so it is possible to get away with a slightly de-normalised structure if it makes working with it easier.  The approach I usually take is to normalise where it makes sense to avoid duplication, and de-normalise where a normalised structure would result in really complicated queries (django doesn't like complicated queries).  I ensure consistency in the data though the use of receivers or overloading the `save` method.